# How to enable SQL Server Agent Tab in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-agent-job

I want to auto schedule the database backups. But in my SQL Server window the SQL Server Agent was disabled.

I try to enable this by start the `SQLSERVERAGENT` service. But it said,

[image]

```
The Operation Could not be completed.
Access is denied.
```

I don't know how to enable this, Please help me to do this.

Comment: I searched for that in google and found this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/975c86b9-3622-418a-8e19-6720a51d7549/access-denied-starting-sql-server-agent?forum=sqlgetstarted. What's the logon acount that it is using? Do you think it has enough access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to set startup type of SQL Server agent to `automatic`:

1. Run `services.msc`,
2. Right-click on `SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)`,
3. Select `Properties`,
4. Change start up type to `automatic` and save,
5. Now start the service,
6. Then you can enable.

I hope this will help you.